# Multilist field with search

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I am using multilist with search field, I put this in the source :

```
StartSearchLocation={AAAF5DC8-662A-4B8C-9E66-52EF5EEDCA20}
```

and first time the list came like this :

[image]

after selecting two items from the list, and click save, the left list is empty :

[image]

I am using **Sitecore 8.1 update 2**

Comment: can you try to reindex item with id {AAAF5DC8-662A-4B8C-9E66-52EF5EEDCA20} from developer tab and if the problem continue to appear write to Sitecore support.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber : I did, and still i have the same issue, it seems it is a bug.

Comment: can you try to rebuild all indexes

Comment: @SitecoreClimber still have the same issue, even after rebuilding all indexes.

Comment: If your StartSearchLocation item is bucket, try to sync it (Configure tab>Sync button) or Revert-Bucket it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and rebuild index of source item worked for me.

Items started appearing in field and search was also working fine. Then I faced new issue, whenever I click on Next/Prev/Refresh button, it was returning duplicate items.

It was due to the items which has multiple versions (Item versions NOT language versions).
Refer link- https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2014/06/21/multilist-with-search-returns-duplicate-results/

The solution is to add Filter=_latestversion:true parameter in data source query. For example:

StartSearchLocation={6A6541F7-5C39-4C40-8FF7-CCD7CB588227}&TemplateFilter={75DCC552-C3B6-56CA-BFA9-371550F116DC}&Filter=_latestversion:true